Is it possible to inject code context into VS Code Javascript language server
in VS Code I want to provide custom JSDocs and autocomplete for javascript.
So I have a js file that contains definitions and JSDocs for specific objects and functions and I would like to have autocomplete and docs on hover, without the file/definitions being present in the current code base/context, but for example via an extension.
I found a solution by creating custom hover providers and use vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider, but this is much less beautiful than what a language server can provide with docs.
My next idea was to somehow inject the file into the current LSP context from within the extension, but I didn't find a way to do this.
Are there ways to do this or achieve something similar or do I have to settle with the first solution?

The linked answers are not really duplicates, as they are about a scenario where you are the one writing/controling the code, and you are able to import stuff to it. This question is more general, about setting up VS Code or authoring a plugin in a way that provides Intellisense context for any code (written by the end-user). A typical scenario could be writing an VS Code extension for users writing code that will be executed in a specific environment in your organisations, where some global functions or variables are available (common in template language environs, like PugJS)
